# Leaflet createTile coords reference to this._tile

Tags: leaflet

In the `createTile` function, I use coords to store a list of 'AbortControllers'. The key I use for every tile creation :

```js
createTile(coords: Coords, done: DoneCallback) {
  const abortController = ...

  const key = this._tileCoordsToKey(coords)
  this.abortControllers[key] = abortController;
}
```

In the initialise function I listen for the `tileunload` function:

```js
TileLayer.WMS.extend({
    initialize: function (url, options) {
      this.on("tileunload", (event) => {
        this._tileCoordsToKey(event.coords);
      });
    }
});
```

This coordsKey from the `tileunload` event does not match the coordsKey I can create in `createTile`. The internal `this._tiles` cache uses a different cache key?

Any way to reference the event coords to the creation coords?

Comment: Please share a demo. For me the key is the same in create and tileunload. [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/UMh1xUfMIkYuWvm9). And the internal cache key uses the `_tileCoordsToKey` too

Comment: Thank you for your demo @FalkeDesign. I tried my simple WMS alternative and this unloads ok. I dig deeper into my more complex extension and come back.